# Можно ли в ChromeOptions задать параметр enableVideo:true?

Tags: java, test-automation, selenide, selenoid

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли как-то с помощью класса ChromeOptions передать настройку enableVideo:true?

для DesiredCapability я знаю как можно передать. Но мне нужно сделать это именно с помощью ChromeOptions

Answer (score 1):

`ChromeOptions` и `DesiredCapability` оба наследуются от `MutableCapabilities` так что задавать так же:

```java
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.setCapability("enableVideo", true);
```